# How to load content with AJAX using links inside the "container/placeholder" div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to load content with AJAX using links located inside the same div. I took a great example from [here](https://github.com/pinceladasdaweb/html5-history-api) that uses History API and is also SEO friendly.

Here's an excerpt of the structure:

**HTML**

```
<body>

    <?php
      $page = 'home'; 
      include('inc/navbar.php'); //Nav bar contains links that will load inside the Placeholder
    ?>

    <div class="placeholder">

      <!-- THIS CONTENT WILL BE LOADED WITH AJAX -->
      <!-- THIS IS WHERE I'M TRYING TO LINK TO INTERNAL PAGES -->

    </div>

    <?php include('inc/footer.php'); ?>

</body>
```

**HTML for nav include**

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li <?php echo ($page == 'page-one') ? "class='active'" : ""; ?>><a href="page-one">Link to Page 1</a></li>
  <li <?php echo ($page == 'page-two') ? "class='active'" : ""; ?>><a href="page-two">Link to Page 2</a></li>
  <li <?php echo ($page == 'page-three') ? "class='active'" : ""; ?>><a href="page-three">Link to Page 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var History = {
    run: function() {
        if(History.detectSupport()){
            this.content($('.nav a'));
            this.pop();
        }
    },
    detectSupport: function() {
        return !!(window.history && history.pushState);
    },
    content: function(el) {
        el.on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).attr('href');

            $('.placeholder').html('<div class="loading" />');

            el.parent().removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent().addClass('active')

            History.ajax(url);
            history.pushState(null, document.title, url);

            if (typeof _gaq !== "undefined" && _gaq !== null) {
                _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', url]);
            }

        });
    },
    pop: function() {
        window.onpopstate = function() {
            var url       = location.pathname,
                pathArray = url.split('/');

            History.ajax(url);

            $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
            if(pathArray[2] == ''){
                $('.nav li:first').addClass('active');
            }else {
                $('a[href="'+pathArray[2]+'"]').parent().addClass('active');
            }
        }
    },
    ajax: function(url) {
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(res) {
                $('.placeholder').remove('.loading');
                $('.placeholder').html($(res).find('.placeholder').html());
                document.title = $(res).filter("title").text();
            }
        });
    }
}

//This function does all the magic
$(function() {
    History.run();
});
```

I tried to run the function inside the `placeholder` DIV and works fine. The problem is that when I try to switch between pages, I have some strange flickering before the page is completely loaded. Another workaround was done too but it doesn't load the variable, needed for History API support and get SEO friendly URLs.

Any help will be really appreciated!